# Square button with rounded shape on hover

Tags: jquery, css, html, button, hover

I designed a call to action box. The idea is to add on hover a rounded shape. This shape need to slide in smoothly. Does anyone an idea or an example how to program this?

[Normal state on the left. On the right the hover state.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp4Gi.png)

Thanks for now.

Arjan

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.square{
  background: #bc82ff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  word-break: break-all;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.square > p{
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.circle{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #a672e9;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: -30px;
  transition: bottom 0.5s;

}
.square:hover > .circle{
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <p>12312312312312312321321312321</p>
</div>
```

You should try to show your efforts.

Refer to this.

Comment: Thanks for you help:)